# Classify a noun into abstract or concrete using NLTK or similar

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

How can I categorize a list of nouns into abstract or concrete in Python?

For example:

```
"Have a seat in that chair."
```

In above sentence `chair` is noun and can be categorized as concrete.

Comment: There is no operational definition of an abstract noun - so, such classification can be done only approximately, empirically.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest training a classifier using pretrained word vectors.

You need two libraries: `spacy` for tokenizing text and extracting word vectors, and `scikit-learn` for machine learning:

```
import spacy
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
```

Distinguishing concrete and abstract nouns is a simple task, so you can train a model with very few examples:

```
classes = ['concrete', 'abstract']
# todo: add more examples
train_set = [
    ['apple', 'owl', 'house'],
    ['agony', 'knowledge', 'process'],
]
X = np.stack([list(nlp(w))[0].vector for part in train_set for w in part])
y = [label for label, part in enumerate(train_set) for _ in part]
classifier = LogisticRegression(C=0.1, class_weight='balanced').fit(X, y)
```

When you have a trained model, you can apply it to any text:

```
for token in nlp("Have a seat in that chair with comfort and drink some juice to soothe your thirst."):
    if token.pos_ == 'NOUN':
        print(token, classes[classifier.predict([token.vector])[0]])
```

The result looks satisfying:

```
# seat concrete
# chair concrete
# comfort abstract
# juice concrete
# thirst abstract
```

You can improve the model by applying it to different nouns, spotting the errors and adding them to the training set under the correct label.

Comment: This is a useful answer but it only goes so far. The knowledge is out there with this kind of work existing in the literature, but I can't find any code to support the work: https://direct.mit.edu/tacl/article/doi/10.1162/tacl_a_00183/43336/Multi-Modal-Models-for-Concrete-and-Abstract

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [WordNet via NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) and explore the hypernym tree of the words you are interested in. WordNet is a lexical database that organises words in a tree-like structure based on their abstraction level. You can use this to get more abstract versions of your target word.

For example, the following example code tells you that that the word "chair" belongs to the category "seats", which belongs to the over-arching category "entity".
The word "anger" on the other hand, belongs to the category "emotion".

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
wn.synsets('chair')
wn.synset('chair.n.01').hypernyms()
# [Synset('seat.n.03')]
wn.synset('chair.n.01').root_hypernyms()
# [Synset('entity.n.01')]

wn.synsets('anger')
wn.synset('anger.n.01').hypernyms()
# [Synset('emotion.n.01')]
```

=> look at the NLTK WordNet documentation and play around with the hypernym trees to categorise words into abstract or concrete categories. You will have to define yourself what exactly you mean by "abstract" or "concrete" and which categories of words you want to put into these two buckets though.

Answer (score -1):

One simple way could be maintain a dictionary of abstract nouns and for unknown words look at suffixes — words with following suffixes are generally abstract nouns:

1. -ship
2. -ism
3. -ity
4. -ness
5. -age
6. -acy
7. -ment
8. -ability, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many more abstract words that do not have any specific suffixes (love, trust, deceit, pride, evil, fear...)

Answer (score -4):

first, tokenize words by word_tokenize(string)
then use pos_tag from nltk.

```
import nltk
from nltk import*

string="Have a seat in that chair."
words=nltk.word_tokenize(string)
nltk.pos_tag(words)
```

This is not tested, but I think it might be almost similar like this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Arnold Chung. From what I understand POS tagger will identify the noun/s in a sentence but does not specify the type of noun. So for e.g., 'Have a seat in that chair' is tagged as "Have/VBP a/DT seat/NN in/IN that/DT chair/NN" in which chair is identified as a noun but the noun type is still unknown. ..?